# How do I detect volume release on flutter android

Tags: flutter

I'm using hardware_buttons: ^1.0.0. but it only detects when you press the button, not when you release it.

```
StreamSubscription _volumeButtonSubscription;

init{
...
_volumeButtonSubscription = volumeButtonEvents.listen((VolumeButtonEvent event) {
      if(event.toString().contains("VolumeButtonEvent.VOLUME_UP")){
        //this part is when the user press volume up
      }
    });
}
```